# My Android studio device manager is not working

Tags: flutter

It keeps showing me allow vt-x in your bios settings which I have done, then it said download haxm which I did what else can I do

Answer (score 1):

You don't have virtualization enabled, so what you need to do is to go to your BIOS and enable virtualization, some PC's have it disabled initially.

Comment: Thanks but I have done this before, is there's something I need to do

Comment: I do not think so